# How compare same two XML elements with another element using Xquery

Tags: xml, comparison, xquery

I am a beginner in Xquery and I have an xml code in which I want to compare two different elements with another element. If those two elements always exists together so I want to print the value of them. To make it more clear, I created an example below of what I have so far:

The XML code :

```
<library>
<Book>
    <title>Title1</title>
    <author>Sam</author>
    <author>Jon</author>
    <author>Ellizabith</author>
    </Book>
<Book>
    <title>Title2</title>
    <author>Ellizabith</author>
    <author>Sam</author>
    <author>Ryan</author>
</Book>
<Book>
    <title>Title3</title>
    <author>Ryan</author>
    <author>Sam</author>
</Book>
</library>
```

from the above example, I need to print Ellizabith and Sam since they exist in Title 1 and Titlte 2, Also I want to print Sam and Ryan since they exists in Title 2 and Title 3 using Xquery.

So is there any way to do it? I didn't find any resource to help me to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misinterpreted at first, but here is a new attempt. This will return some duplicates which I might fix later if I have time (fixed now)

```
for $book in //Book
let $authors := $book/author
for $authorA in $authors, $authorB in ($authors[. gt $authorA])
where ($book/following::Book)[author = $authorA and author = $authorB]
return <result>{($authorA, $authorB)}</result>
```

Comment: Thanks for you. But this will print only all the authors who are repeated more than once, but not necessarily any two of them belongs to same title. So do you have an idea how to check if they belongs to same title?

Comment: @ Ewout Graswinckel, I tried this answer and it works. Thanks a lot :)